# Firebase android app class not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase

Hi guys I have this problem I add in firebase the data Lat and Long, I want to retrieve them each time I add a child  I created a class.

```
public class add_marker {
private String Lat;
private String Lang;
public add_marker(){}

public add_marker(String Lat, String Lang)
{
    this.Lat=Lat;
    this.Lang=Lang;

}


public String getLat() {
    return Lat;
}

public void setLat(){ this.Lat=Lat;}

public String getLang() {
    return Lang;
}

public void setLang(){this.Lang=Lang;}
```

}

and I call this class in the code below

Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://androidal.firebaseio.com/markera");

```
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
            //add_marker newPost = snapshot.getValue(add_marker.class);
            add_marker newPost = snapshot.getValue(add_marker.class);  // create new object from the class
           String m1 = snapshot.getKey(); // test get keys from firebase  this works generates all ekys 

            System.out.println(m1); // print my keys 

        }
```

I want to retrive them and create anytime an object then add the Lat and Lang to a map fragment in android.

Where I am wrong each time I try to generate the Object : add_marker newPost = snapshot.getValue(add_marker.class);  the app crash. I am not finding where I am doing wrong :(

Please can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

I guess

> Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://androidal.firebaseio.com/markera");

won´t work with the new Firebase. I remember that I have seen an exception in this case when I tried it by my own.
You should call instead

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("markera")
```